# Standard salesforce css not loading until action function

Tags: css, datepicker, salesforce

I am working on a visualforce page using an inputField on custom object with a date field and looks something like this:

```
<apex:page id="myVisualForcePage" showheader="false" controller="myController">
    <apex:composition template="myTemplate">
        <apex:define name="body">
            <apex:outputpanel id="fullPage">
                <div class="form-group">

                    !A bunch of other stuff!

                    <label class="col-xs-4">My Date</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <apex:inputfield id="myDate" styleClass="form-control" value="{!myControllerObject.MyCustomDateField__c}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:define>
    <apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

For some reason the datePicker is not being formatted correctly on page load until an actionFunction is called.

This appears to be because the some of the standard salesforce css styling classes do not load on page load until the call is made.

When the page is loaded, we can see that the datePicker does not have the standard elements.css class associated with it and there is no link to the style class:

[Datepicker Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvYBR.png)

[Datepicker Element Styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cTGj.png)

[CSS links before callout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQM5t.png)

Following a call to the action function, we can see below that all of salesforce's standard css styling classes are loaded and that the datepicker now has styling elements from element.css which was loaded:

[Newly loaded css styling links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY6YE.png)

[New element styles for date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XczGX.png)

If anyone has any information about why this may be happening and how to ensure the resources are loaded on page load I would really appreciate it!

As an update, if I load the following resource resource explicitly then it will work correctly:

```
<link href="/sCSS/41.0/sprites/1516644206000/Theme3/default/gc/elements.css" type="text/css" class="user" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

However, I do not need to do this on other pages and I am wondering why? Could this be a difference in API's?

Comment: Try checking out here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This behaviour sounds quite weird! On the other pages that work, do they all use the same template?

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same template as the other pages that work

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `showHeader=false` you're declaring you don't want any SF "overhead" on your page, including stylesheets.

Check [`<apex:page>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) and consider explicitly adding `standardStylesheets="true"`... In theory it's a default but looks like you uncovered some funny behavio(u)r.

> **standardStylesheets**: A Boolean value that specifies whether the standard Salesforce stylesheets are added to the generated page header
>   if the showHeader attribute is set to false. If set to true, the
>   standard stylesheets are added to the generated page header. If not
>   specified, this value defaults to true. By setting this to false,
>   components that require Salesforce.com CSS may not display correctly,
>   and their styling may change between releases.

Comment: I have tried playing around with the standard style sheets. If standardStyleSheets is set to false, of course the datepicker won't load at all and if it is explicitly set to true, the same behaviour occurs (the default is working).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this issue, try changing your visualforce page's API version. I find that v39 works fine but I had a page on v41 and v44 that both had this problem.